# What is time complexity when using object for sorting?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity

I have a socket with realtime values. I get the unsorted row object then I need to create a list of the received objects and sort them by price.
After this, my data is sorted correctly.
I am using object for this problem. like this:

```
const data={};
function createListAndSort(row){
  data[row.price]=row;
  return Object.values(data); // return sorted data   
}

socket.onMessage=(row)=>{
  createListAndSort(row)
}
```

My row data is real time but this have three property like this:

```
row = {id: 1 , price: 15664, name: 'test'}
```

In this method, although the values are entered in a specific order, they are automatically sorted into the object due to the number of the keys. like this:
[image]

As mentioned, the received data are not sorted and may reach us in any order. And that the output data were also sorted with this method.
I need to know if the time complexity of this method is less or using the sort function.
what is auto sort time complexity in object?

Comment: There is no "sorting" happening in your code. Object property names are not sorted. When you *retrieve* the property names, they are shown in the order in which they were added to the object. If you want to sort the property values, you have to extract them into an array and then sort the array.

Comment: @Pointy the OP seems to be referring to positive integer keys in the object which are returned before non-integer string keys when retrieving properties.

Comment: Yes, and whether those are "sorted" *as they are stored* is not specified; the platform does whatever it does. Upon retrieval, the numeric (integer) keys will be presented in ascending numeric order; are they sorted at that time? Were they already sorted? That's not knowable without familiarity with how the runtime works internally. Also, of course, it doesn't matter.

Comment: _but I need to sort the received objects by price_ - aren't they already sorted by price? I mean, `data[row.price]`, your objects are listed from lowest price to highest, no?

Comment: In Javascript, whether the property names are in any particular order depends on context. See [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties) and [Does JavaScript guarantee object property order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order). You can't depend on order unless you have control over what javascript engine is being used. And even then, you may still not be able to depend on order.

Comment: my data is sorted correctly with this method. I need to know if the time complexity of this method is less or the sorting function?

Comment: @SaeedMansoori Very unlikely. `data[row.price]=row;` is not `O(1)` here, you won't get better than the theoretical best time complexity. This is somewhere between bucket sort and insertion sort - and it depends on the details of the array/object implementation of the js engine you use to execute this code.

Comment: see: [Complexity of accessing data in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266944/complexity-of-accessing-data-in-an-object), [What is the complexity of retrieval/insertion in JavaScript associative arrays (dynamic object properties) in the major javascript engines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067404/what-is-the-complexity-of-retrieval-insertion-in-javascript-associative-arrays) and [Object.keys() complexity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716812/object-keys-complexity) with answer by a V8 engineer. TLDR object property implementation is engine specific.

Comment: Notice that your implementation has a crucial bug: it cannot handle multiple rows with the same price

Comment: we don't have multiple price, we have many price for buy/sell order queue in stock market. these queues has change every moment and if received Duplicate price must be replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using objects for tabular/list data isn't optimal. You miss all array methods you could utilize to manipulate your data. Always use arrays. For your case just collect rows in an array and sort by the price property. While pushing items into an object to get them sorted is faster, on real-case data size the benefit is rather questionable.

Regarding your case the algorithm is implementation specific, a black box. My guess it's a binary search + insert which is O(log N).

Regarding your question in the comment

> I need to know if the time complexity of this method is less or the sorting function?

My guess is yes, since the object property insert algorithm knows already that the property keys are sorted while the array sort func doesn't have this information.

Comment: I know, this object is only used to store received data and sort. After sorting where I need to use this data and display it in the table, I convert it into an array. By using `Object.values(data)`

Comment: I accepted your answer. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255306/discussion-between-saeed-mansoori-and-alexander-nenashev).